# How to create custom object inside an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

JSON:(this.schedulerForm.get("schedularList").value => this array has contains below array.. )

```
    const result = [{
                     formula_id:1,
                     quantity1:10,
                     quantity2:20,
                     quantity3:40
                     }]
```

conversion JSON:(Above JSON array contains 1 object with 3 quantity value. I need to seperate quantity value in each object with same formula_id along with month and year.. output should be like shown below.)

```
    const result = [{
                      formula_id:1,
                      year:this.year,
                      month: this.month,
                      quantity:10
                      },
                       {
                      formula_id:1,
                      year:this.year,
                      month: this.month,
                      quantity:20
                      },
                      {
                      formula_id:1,
                      year:this.year,
                      month: this.month,
                      quantity:40
                      }]
```

component.ts:

```
 month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  year = new Date().getFullYear();
  getDate(n){
    const date = new Date();
     return date.getMonth() + n;
  }
 save() {
    console.log(this.schedulerForm.get("schedularList").value)
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is still irrelative to Angular and Reactive Forms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will help you:

```js
const data = [{
  formula_id:1,
  quantity1:10,
  quantity2:20,
  quantity3:40
}];

const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const month = 13;

const mapItem = obj => propQuantity => ({
  formula_id: obj.formula_id,
  year, 
  month,
  quantity: obj[propQuantity]
});

const props = ["quantity1", "quantity2", "quantity3"];

const result = data.reduce((agg, obj) => [...agg, ...props.map(mapItem(obj))], []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.. How to do vice versa of this solution??

Comment: Could you please tell how to do vice versa??? i have tried using groupby function but not getting proper data..

Comment: You are asking to reconstruct the original array?

Comment: @Rekha sorry for the delay, i prepared a jsfiddle with the code that you asking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/kevynsax/en21m4zu/13/
please let me know if this attend your needs